# Camel SpringBoot Maven to Gradle

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle, apache-camel

This is a question on Gradle.
I tried to use Gradle to build the Camel sample
[Camel SpringBoot Example](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-spring-boot/pom.xml). I was able to build and run the sample using with Maven, but I was not able to come up with a Gradle script (I have tried gradle init on the POM, but also failed) that can build the sample within runtime error.

The maven built downloaded many dependencies, so I have the feeling that I had missed out many in my Gradle script.

I would greatly appreciate if a Gradle expert can share a script with me.

Comment: Try to reformat your question as a general Gradle one and not specific to one product. Attach you logs, error you get and content of you build scripts.

Comment: My gradle file is https://github.com/yctang888/cameltest .
 The dependencies are  much fewer than that fetched by using the maven build. I'm not sure whether there is a smarter way to add the dependencies to the gradle script. Compile was fine but there were runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated an new version of the Gradle script that seems to work.
The problem was solved by studying the running errors for classes not available and also by studying the file named DEPENDENCIES generated by the Maven build.
I'm just a mediocre Gradle user, but it looks like that the maven script is much more compact and requiring less guess work.